# How to delete Azure app service folder using powershell or any script before the Azure Devops deployment

Tags: powershell, directory, delete-file, azure-web-app-service

Can you please help me out with the solution on below 
1.I already configured the CI in Azure DevOps 
2.In CD i need a Powerhell or any script for deletion of Azure App service folder before the deployment.
3.I know the process of Kudo also but this process is manually.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$WebAppName = “insert Web App name”
$slotName = “insert Slot Name”
$username = ‘insert the username from the publish profile’ #From the publish profile
$password = “insert the password from the publish profile” #From the publish profile
# Initialize parameters for Invoke-RestMethod
$apiUrl = “https://$WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/&#8221;
if ($slotName -ne “”){
    $apiUrl = “https://$webAppName`-$slotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/”
}
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes((“$($username):$($password)”)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization=“Basic $($base64AuthInfo)”
    ‘If-Match’ = ‘*’
}
$userAgent = “powershell/2.0”
# Define a reursive function to delete files
function DeleteKuduDir ($content, $dir)
{
    foreach($c in $content)
    {      
        if($c.mime -eq “inode/directory”)
        {
            # Get listing of directory as an array
            $childContent = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $c.href –Headers $headers –UserAgent $userAgent –Method GET –ContentType “application/json”
           
            # Delete directory
            $newDir = $dir + (Split-Path $c.href –leaf) + “\”
            DeleteKuduDir –content $childContent –dir $newDir
        }
        # Delete file
        $file = Split-Path $c.href –leaf
        Write-Host “Deleting” $dir$file    
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $c.href –Headers $headers –UserAgent $userAgent –Method DELETE –ContentType “application/json”
    }
}
# Get listing of wwwroot as an array
$rootContent = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $apiUrl –Headers $headers –UserAgent $userAgent –Method GET –ContentType “application/json”
# Delete files and directory in wwwroot
DeleteKuduDir –content $rootContent –dir “\”
Write-Host “Done!”
```

Comment: I am getting below error  
Invoke-RestMethod : 
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Server Error
 
  401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
  You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
 
At line:33 char:16

Comment: + ... otContent = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $apiUrl –Headers $headers –UserAge ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:27 char:28

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand
 
Deleting \
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:29 char:42

Comment: +         $result = Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $c.href –Headers $headers –U ...
+                                          ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand